# bashrc - want to append to a variable

Tags: string, bash, append

I know in C++, you can do the following:

```
string Var = "";
for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
    Var=std::to_string(i) + " ";
    Var+=Var; 
}
cout << "Var: " << Var << endl;
```

The end result would be: "Var: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14".

How would I achieve the following in a bashrc script?

Comment: you might want to look at this link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105517/concatenating-string-variable-inside-a-for-loop-in-the-bash-shell . Its doing the same thing. Also the code above in C++ will only print"Var: 14 14"

Comment: In bash, catenation is catenation, no need for an operator.  `MYVAR="$MYVAR glorf"` adds "glorf" to $MYVAR

Comment: Why not `var=$(echo $(seq 0 14))`

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /bin/bash
var=''
for i in {0..14} ; do
    var+=$i' '
done
echo Var: $var
```

Answer (score 1):

[choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37998493/45375) works well with a *fixed* iteration count, but won't work with *variables*, because the sequence form of Bash's brace expansion feature (`{0..14}`) only works with *literals*.

Thus, using Bash's C-style arithmetic loop is generally preferable:

```
var=''
count=15  # variable iteration count
for (( i = 0; i < count; ++i )); do # note that vars. need no $ inside (( ... ))
  var+="$i " # append, using string interpolation (in *double* quotes)
done
echo "Var: $var" # double-quote what to echo to prevent unwanted interpretation.
```